# Hyper-V GPU Passthrough with NVidia A100 no display

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, windows-server-2019, nvidia, gpu

I am currently trying to get some NVidia A100 GPUs to work on our Hyper-V Hypervisor. I managed to setup the GPU Passthrough to a VM but the problem is I don't get a video display. I assume the problem is that the NVidia A100s don't have a framebuffer, thus no display output. So is there a way to force Hyper-V to add its Hyper-V Video Adapter as main display adapter instead of the A100?

I experimented around a bit and found out that if you passthrough exactly 3 GPUs (A100) to one VM and also increase the High memory Mapped IO Space to 768GB with `Set-VM -HighMemoryMappedIoSpace 768GB` I indeed get a display output, because the Hyper-V video adapter gets added to the VM. But it seems that this only works on a Windows Guest system. On a Linux (ubuntu) guest I don't get a display anymore as soon as I install nvidia drivers. I don't know why this only happens when I passthrough 3 GPUs but I wanted to try to manually "force" a hyper-v video adapter to the VM, so maybe I also get a display output with one passthrough GPU? Is there any way to do that?